# Mousemove position isn't smooth on live site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a mousemove effect on my zoom image. everything is going perfectly on my local server but when it's on the live server the `object-position` moving animation is not smooth. it's jumping and lagging and not update with mousemove. Here is the [live site](https://lovegen.codesign.com.bd/store/new/) I am facing a problem.Click a product image then open the zoom image by clicking the image and see the lagging mousemove animation.can someone give me the right solution that I missed here? Thanks in Advance

**Javascript Code**

```
 var image = document.querySelector('.single-zoom-img img');
    image.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      (document.documentElement as any).style.overflow = 'hidden';
      var valueY = Math.round(e.pageY) / 12;
      requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        image.style.objectPosition = `center ${Math.min(100, valueY)}%`;
      });
    });
```

**CSS Code**

```
.single-zoom-img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  overflow: hidden;
  will-change: transform;

  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 50% 0%;
    transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems smooth to me. Can you record the effect?

Comment: it's actually difficult to record. Because sometimes it seems okay and sometimes not. If I came from another product it seems lagging. actually it should move on mousemove accordingly. But it's not doing that.@RobertAndrosz

Comment: From what I see you use pretty CPU intensive stuff so I'd say take a look at the Chrome debugging console and go to the 'performance' tab also take a look at the 'animation' tab. I would also suggest you take a look at Hardware Accelerated CSS https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css may solve your problem on modern Web Browsers.

Comment: @geauser I already have seen that before. it's not working for my case.  my problem is I have to move the image background position that's why I need to change object-position here dynamically. the article says about when we use translate3d  we have to use those CSS properties to work smoothly. but in my case how can I achieve smoothness with using object-position or any other solution to move image position top to bottom.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your problem @RaydoanAnik but instead of using object-position have you tried to use `position: relative` and change the `left` and `top` value according to the mouse movements? Also as I stated above, your are using rather expensive CSS properties, one of them being `transition: all` especially with the `cubic-bezier` function. Replace the `all` with `object-position` and use a `linear` easing function, it may help... Also look at your FPS counter https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/

Comment: Thanks for you guide @geauser. it does still not solve yet